# Get a value based on another one

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm using Java and `import javax.xml.xpath.*` package.

I'm a beginner with XPATH and I can not recover a value based on another value.

**Here my .xml file**

```
<lom:lom xmlns:lom="http://ltsc.ieee.org/xsd/LOM" xmlns:lomfr="http://www.lom-fr.fr/xsd/LOMFR" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <lom:general>
          ...
          <lom:title>
              <lom:string language="fre">Analyse financière bilan : Un exemple d'approche financière par la méthode des ratios - la centrale de bilans de la Banque de France</lom:string>
         </lom:title>
         ...
    </lom:general>

    <lom:lifeCycle>
        ...
        <lom:contribute>
            <lom:role>
                <lom:source>LOMv1.0</lom:source>
                <lom:value>author</lom:value>
            </lom:role>
            <lom:entity>BEGIN:VCARD VERSION:3.0 N:GARROT;Thierry;;; FN:Thierry GARROT EMAIL;TYPE=INTERNET:thierry.garrot@unice.fr ORG:Université de Nice END:VCARD</lom:entity>
            <lom:date>
                <lom:dateTime>2009-10-07</lom:dateTime>
            </lom:date>
        </lom:contribute>
        <lom:contribute>
             <lom:role>
                 <lom:source>LOMv1.0</lom:source>
                 <lom:value>instructional designer</lom:value>
             </lom:role>
             <lom:entity>BEGIN:VCARD VERSION:3.0 N:CASANOVA;Gérard;;; FN:Gérard CASANOVA EMAIL;TYPE=INTERNET:gerard.casanova@univ-nancy2.fr ORG:Université de Lorraine END:VCARD</lom:entity>
             <lom:date>
                 <lom:dateTime>2009-10-07</lom:dateTime>
             </lom:date>
        </lom:contribute>
        <lom:contribute>
             ...
        </lom:contribute>
        ...
    </lom:lifeStyle>
 </lom>
```

How can I get `lom:entity` value only if `lom:value` value is `author`?

`lom:entity` is a VCARD but I think that it's a problem because I have an algorithm to get author fullname.

**Example:**

To get `lom:title` I use : `//*[local-name()='title']/*[local-name()='string']/text()`.

Thank's for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XPath expression you are looking for is (expecting a proper namespace handling):

```
/lom:lom/lom:lifeCycle/lom:contribute[lom:role/lom:value = 'author']/lom:entity
```

This should give you the desired content.

A namespace ignoring variant of the above XPath expression is

```
/*[local-name()='lom']/*[local-name()='lifeCycle']/*[local-name()='contribute'][*[local-name()='role']/*[local-name()='value'] = 'author']/*[local-name()='entity']
```

Comment: @N.Lamblin: My presumption was a proper namespace handling. I can only guess that this is the problem you have.

Comment: Possible ... But in this case why the expression to get the title is working? :/

Comment: @N.Lamblin: Because with you expression `*[local-name()='title']` and `*[local-name()='string']` you were skipping any namespaces. I'm gonna add a namespace-ignorant version of my expression.

Comment: @N.Lamblin: I added a (somewhat ridiculous) version of my answer. It does work, but the previous version was far more elegant. Sorry to mention that.

Comment: With the version which ignore namespace, it's working. Thank's a lot! I will try to understand why the first version is not works ... :)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get `lom:entity` value only if `lom:value` value is `author`?

**`xpath`** expression:

```
//lom:entity[parent::lom:contribute/lom:role/lom:value="author"]/text()
```

Comment: Like zx485 I get an empty result :/

Comment: @N.Lamblin, verify your input structure with XML validator beforehand